# why these dependency error while sudo apt upgrade?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, dependencies

```
tsheri@DESKTOP-9BSR0SP:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt-utils : Depends: apt (= 1.6.3) but 1.6.6ubuntu0.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: To answer this question, we would need to know the name and version of your Linux distribution (Debian? Ubuntu? Something else?) and the list of `apt` package repositories you have configured in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and in any `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` files, if they exist.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... the version numbers seem to match Ubuntu Bionic (18.04).

It looks like you've somehow ended up with an incomplete update: normally the packages `apt` and `apt-utils` should both have the same versions, but it looks like your system has a January 2019 security update to `apt` installed but `apt-utils` did not receive a matching update at that time.

This is supposed to be impossible if you use only `apt upgrade` or similar tools to update your system. Was the security update installed using `dpkg -i` or similar low-level package tool, bypassing `apt`?

Anyway, the proper fix should be to update both `apt` and `apt-utils` packages to matching, current versions.

Because the version `1.6.6ubuntu0.1` of both `apt` and `apt-utils` may already be superseded by newer versions on the repository servers, the command `sudo apt --fix-broken install` might be unable to perform the minimal fix of just upgrading `apt-utils` to the version matching your current `apt` package. If that happens, try `sudo apt upgrade apt apt-utils`: this gives the command an explicit permission to upgrade both packages in order to achieve a valid combination.